# Return 2 rows when populating table using map function

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a Semantic-UI-React Table in my code that I constructed like this:

```
<Table striped celled fixed textAlign="center">
    <Table.Body>{activeLogList}</Table.Body>
</Table>
```

I populate this table with my Log List and a map function:

```
 const activeLogList = this.state.activeLogList.map(logEntry => (
  <Table.Row key={logEntry.event}>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.event}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{this.formatTime(logEntry.time)}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.model}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.ip}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.description}</Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
))
```

**The thing is:** Since I am building this activeLogList using map, I can only return one element, and that is **1 Table.Row**, but in some cases I need to return **2 Table.Row** like this:

```
const activeLogList = this.state.activeLogList.map(logEntry => (
  <Table.Row key={logEntry.event}>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.event}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{this.formatTime(logEntry.time)}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.model}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.ip}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.description}</Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>
  <Table.Row>
    SOMETHING GOES HERE
  </Table.Row>      
))
```

The code doesn't compile if I try to do that, so....

**The question is:** What is a reasonable way that I populate this table when sometimes I need to return two table rows in the map function instead of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react you can render (or return) only one parent component, to solve this normally you would wrap everything with a large `<div>` but you can't do it in this case so you should use `React.Fragment`, this component does not generate a new HTML element

```
const activeLogList = this.state.activeLogList.map(logEntry => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Table.Row key={logEntry.event}>
      <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.event}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{this.formatTime(logEntry.time)}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.name}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.model}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.ip}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.description}</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
    <Table.Row>
      SOMETHING GOES HERE
    </Table.Row>
  </React.Fragment>      
))
```

There is a shorthand for `<React.Fragment>`, is `<>` for opening and `</>` for closing, but is not supported by all parsers yet, `React.Fragment` is safer by now and also support the `key` attribute.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react ^16.x.x you can use an `array of components` instead of a fragment:

```
const activeLogList = this.state.activeLogList.map(logEntry => ([
  <Table.Row key={logEntry.event}>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.event}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{this.formatTime(logEntry.time)}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.name}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.model}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.ip}</Table.Cell>
    <Table.Cell verticalAlign="middle">{logEntry.description}</Table.Cell>
  </Table.Row>,
  <Table.Row key="custom row">
    SOMETHING GOES HERE
  </Table.Row>
]))
```

Notice: remember to add a key on every array element to avoid warnings